# change datatypes of a table in sql-server in a c# program

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server

I'm trying to change the datatype of some columns in a sql-server table. I need to convert some, but not all, columns from varchar to int.

I have tried the following code

```
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(null, conn);

command.CommandText = "select sum(CountInput) from " + tableName;

int linecodes = Convert.ToInt32(command.ExecuteScalar());

Console.WriteLine(linecodes + " lines of code");
```

but I get an error message:

"Operand data type varchar is invalid for sum operator"

Comment: The question doesn't make sense. Going by the query and  error, the `CountInput` field is a string instead of a numeric value. You need to convert *the field* to the correct type, not cover it up by some conversion. A conversion will result in far worse performance as the database won't be able to use indexes and optimizations to speed up calculations

Comment: Maybe my english skills are not very high. Of course I know that the column CountInput is from type varchar and this is way the program is not working. But i want to know is there any possibility to change the datatype from this column to int with a c# command?

Comment: "I have no idea how I can do this." - this makes me really sad.

Comment: @Arvo Sorry but i tried to explain my question it makes me sad to that you downvoted it and i cant ask any question anymore

Comment: @Arturka1 I didn't downvote but I understand those who did - they are warning you. You were downvoted because you asked a bad question. You should read [How do I ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) in the help center to see what is considered a good question and what is wrong with this question: The question sounds like a "Fix this for me" question which is considered bad form. You have a clear error message which you try to ignore. You ask for something that doesn't makes sense (change the type of a SQL column from C#).

Comment: @Arturka1 Bad questions are downvoted at best. At worst, they are ignored or receive equally bad answers.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos i don't ignore the error message, i just cannot found a way to fix it. Why does it makes no sense to change it from c#?

Comment: Change the type of the column in the database from varchar to int or decimal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

is the CountInput column on your database a valid numerical column?

Can you manually run the SQL this code is producing? It looks like the SQL is going wrong not the .Net code.

Comment: This isn't an answer, it should be a comment

Comment: I couldn't add a comment because of my rep... figured it was better to reply with an answer than just ignore the question. Happy to have it removed and someone else comment if they can